# Objective-C newbie question re: global instances

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, singleton

Is there a way to make one (1) instance of an object and share that instance between different files?

For instance, I have Class "A" (created in fileA.m), and I create an instance of it in a different file (fileB.m).  Now, I want to use that same instance created in fileB.m in several other files (fileC.m and fileD.m) so I can share ivar's (such as a database).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would want Class A to be a singleton. Here's a [great guide](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) to help you out with that.

Comment: Great guide... exactly what I was looking for, not only to clear up my question, but also to show me how to do it.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a static class method as a constructor which will return a singleton instance of the object you're looking for.